# What´s the correct way to stop pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having problems with my Kubernetes cluster. I have a service with a deployment associated. I have several replicas of the pods in this deployment up and running and 2 containers for each deployment.

I'm using a `Rolling Update`strategy for redeploying, with parameters `maxSurge : 1` and `maxUnavailable: 0`. When I change a deployment the pods are changing correctly, adding one new pod and then deleting an old one until the whole deployment is changed.

However, on the switch of the first pod from old to new, I'm having a small outage. This doesn't happend when I'm changing the other pods, that is, when there is at least one new pod up and running.

What can I do to fix this issue? I have a `livenessProbe` and a `readinessProbe` but still it looks like the new pod is not ready to receive traffic when it just starts, although the readinessProbe works correctly. I've read that in some applications the pod doesn't close with a SIGTERM as Kubernetes expects and therefore the pod is abruptly killed. I'm wondering if this is the problem but can't be sure. What would be the correct way to handle this in the `preStop`? Is there something that I could be missing?

Comment: Did you take a look https://blog.gruntwork.io/gracefully-shutting-down-pods-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-328aecec90d and https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace . Have you consider using terminationgraceperiodseconds ?

Comment: I'm using terminationGracePeriodSeconds already, with a big number. I've noticed that this problem only happens if my kubectl apply actually changes something. If the definition of the resources doesn't change, there is no outage, although the rollout os performed correctly. Could that be related with the problem?

Comment: Share your deployment manifest and the exact commands you are using to change the deployment object